# Rails 5.0 - Comments not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, model-view-controller

I'm implementing comments as a nested resource for an events app and hitting one issue after another. Initially it worked fine, however, the only functionality they had was create & destroy. I want to add an edit function using Ajax/remote: true for same page editing (never done it before) and I've hit a wall. The edit link_to doesn't/has never worked and now even the create function doesn't work. This is what's coming through on the development log -

```
Processing by CommentsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "comment"=>{"body"=>"Comment."}, "commit"=>"Create Comment", "event_id"=>"27"}
  [1m[36mComment Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", nil], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)



ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Comment with 'id'=):
```

I've tried all sorts of different parameters via trial and error but the 'id' issue keeps springing up. Here's my code -

**comments_controller.rb**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController


    before_action :set_comment, only: [:show, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]


    def create
        @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
        @comment = @event.comments.create(comment_params)
        @comment.user_id = current_user.id

        if @comment.save
            redirect_to @event
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end


    # GET /comments/1/edit
    def edit
        @event = @comment.event
        @comment = @event.comments.find(params[:id])
        respond_to do |f|
            f.js 
            f.html 
        end
    end

    def show
    end



    def update 
        if @comment.update(comment_params)
            redirect_to @event, notice: "Comment was successfully updated!"
        else
            render 'edit'
        end
    end



    def destroy
        @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
        @comment = @event.comments.find(params[:id])
        @comment.destroy

        redirect_to event_path(@event)
    end

    private

    def set_comment
      @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_event
        @event = Event.find(params[:event_id])
    end


    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:name, :body)
    end


end
```

**_comment.html.erb**

```
<div class="comment clearfix">
  <div class="comment_content">
    <div id="<%=dom_id(comment)%>" class="comment">  
      <p class="comment_name"><strong><%= comment.name %></strong></p>
      <p class="comment_body"><%= comment.body %></p>

  </div>

      <p><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_event_comment_path([comment.event, comment]), id: "comment", remote: true %></p>
                  <p><%= link_to 'Delete', [comment.event, comment],
                                     method: :delete,
                                        class: "button",
                              data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**_form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for([@event, @comment], remote: true) do |f| %>


    <%= f.label :comment %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :body %><br>
    <br>
    <%= f.button :submit, label: 'Add Comment', class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

**edit.js.erb**

```
$('#comment').append('<%= j render 'form' %>');
```

I think I'm getting mixed up with the 'id's for this thing and how to get the `remote: true` function working on the page. I don't want to accept defeat but I may have to if I don't get this working.

UPDATE -

When I try and edit an existing comment I get this in my development log -

```
Started GET "/events/27%2F32/comments/27/edit" for ::1 at 2017-05-24 12:28:20 +0100
Processing by CommentsController#edit as JS
  Parameters: {"event_id"=>"27/32", "id"=>"27"}
  [1m[36mComment Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "comments".* FROM "comments" WHERE "comments"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 27], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)




ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Comment with 'id'=27):
```

The route doesn't make sense - `"/events/27%2F32/comments/27/edit"` - the comment id should be 32 and the event id 27.

**routes.rb**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

     devise_for :users, :controllers => { omniauth_callbacks: "omniauth_callbacks", registrations: "registrations" }  


  resources :users
  # the above resource draws out routes for user profiles
  resources :events do

    resources :comments
    resources :bookings

  end





    root 'events#index'
```

Comment: At which line you get that error?

Comment: Could you inspect your link html to be sure the Comment id is present in href ?

Comment: @Pavan That's from when I click on 'create comment'

Comment: @HoloHokkaido You mean in the routes? Yes, its definitely suppossed to be there. I've looked via console and it shows on the comment info but I can't seem to get it to come through the parameters.

Comment: @Mike.Whitehead Not in console, but in your web page, generated by rails. (Click right on the link on your web page and select "inspect", then look at what is in "href" attribute). Or just look at what URL your browser indicates when your mouse is over the link.

Comment: Could you show us what you get by doing a `rails routes -g comment` ?

Comment: @HoloHokkaido This is what I get for edit -      edit_event_comment GET    /events/:event_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format) comments#edit

Comment: It seems to think that event_id is comment_id/event_id (hence the `27%2F32`). Could you show us your routes.rb file ?

Comment: @HoloHokkaido added

Comment: @Mike.Whitehead Ok it seems correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change

```
before_action :set_comment, only: [:show, :create, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

to

```
before_action :set_comment, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

you can't set comment when you are creating it.

Also, as discussed in the comments, your edit link should be,

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', [comment.event, comment], id: "comment", remote: true %>
```

Comment: I agree, but how do I do that?

Comment: to `edit`, not `create`, those are two different actions and serve different purposes. at time of creating comment, comment doesn't exist, thus `id` is `nil` and so `couldn't find with id=`

Comment: @Mike.Whitehead I showed you, remove `:create` from your only array.

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon I've done that but edit still doesn't work. Can you see why this might be happening?

Comment: @Mike.Whitehead Your links are wrong.`<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_event_comment_path([comment.event, comment]), id: "comment", remote: true %>` should be `<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_event_comment_path(comment.event, comment), id: "comment", remote: true %>` or `<%= link_to 'Edit', [comment.event, comment], id: "comment", remote: true %>`

Comment: try above fix, it should work, your params are passing wrong

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon Which link do I use?

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon     Tried the second one - the routes are now working, however, I'm now getting this in my development log - 'No template found for CommentsController#show, rendering head :no_content' - I think this is now to do with the javascript side.

Comment: well, that's because you have not created a view for `show` in comments. Rails redirects to show after creating any record. you need to handle the redirection.

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon Do I do that in the conventional way or do i need a js.erb file also?

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon Well, I want the edit function to work in-line so that's really the point. Do all nested resource html files need an underscore like _show.html.erb ?

Comment: @Mike.Whitehead You should read this page : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Comment: that's the syntax for partials, as suggested by @HoloHokkaido, please refer the documentation as this is way out of scope of question. Please accept the answer here and raise another question if you have any

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon Sure, if you update your answer to include the part about the links then I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon Actually that was somebody else. Don't worry, I've done it.